# R Data Structure Setup for Reproducible Research

Tags: r, reproducible-research

**Background**

I get hourly interval reports on equipment in buildings, a lot of buildings and a lot of equipment. Each parameter on the equipment is called a point and they already have a name, I don't get to choose the name of the point. Each point name is unique. What I'm trying to do is run a standard report on each building. Eventually, I'd like to move this to Shiny and look at my graphs and maybe print a report from there, but... baby steps.

**Question**

*Am I on the right track? Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Am I going to run into problems when I start to write Markdown reports or transfer this over to Shiny?*

**Sample Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(55)


test_func <- function(pointa, pointb, mult) {
  out = (pointb - pointa) * mult
  return(out)
}

test_fail <- function(pointa, pointb) {
  out = ifelse(pointa > (pointb - 9), 1, 0)
  return(out)
}

tbl.data <- data.frame(
  date = c(rep("2/1/2018", 24),
           rep("2/2/2018", 24),
           rep("2/3/2018", 24),
           rep("2/4/2018", 24),
           rep("2/5/2018", 24),
           rep("2/6/2018", 24),
           rep("2/7/2018", 24)),
  hour = rep(0:23, 7),
  equipa.vala = runif(168, min = 50, max = 60),
  equipb.vala = runif(168, min = 50, max = 60)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    equipa.valb = 10 + equipa.vala * runif(168, min = 0.75, max = 1.25),
    equipb.valb = 10 + equipb.vala * runif(168, min = 0.75, max = 1.25)
  )

tbl.equip <- data.frame(
  equipment.id = c(1,2),
  equipment.name = c("equipa", "equipb"),
  equipment.mult = c(5, 7)
)

tbl.point <- data.frame(
  point = c("equipa.vala", "equipa.valb", "equipb.vala", "equipb.valb"),
  equipment = c("equipa", "equipa", "equipb", "equipb"),
  category = c("vala", "valb", "vala", "valb")
)

for (eq in tbl.equip[,2]) {

  vala <- as.character(
    tbl.point$point[tbl.point$equipment == eq &
                            tbl.point$category == "vala"]
  )
  valb <- as.character(
    tbl.point$point[tbl.point$equipment == eq &
                            tbl.point$category == "valb"]
  )

  equip.mult <- as.numeric(
    tbl.equip$equipment.mult[tbl.equip$equipment.name == eq]
  )

  for.data <- tbl.data %>%
    select_(cola = vala,
            colb = valb) %>%
    mutate(
      result = test_func(cola, colb, equip.mult),
      fault = test_fail(cola, colb)
    )

  score <- sum(for.data$fault)/length(for.data$fault)
  savings <- sum(for.data$result[for.data$result > 0])

  p1 <- ggplot(for.data, aes(x = colb, y = cola, color = as.factor(fault))) +
    geom_point() +
    annotate("text", label = paste("savings is:", savings), x = 50, y = 60) +
    annotate("text", label = paste("score is:", score), y = 51, x = 80) +
    ggtitle(paste("Equipment:", eq)) +
    theme_minimal()
  print(p1)
}
```

**Explanation**

So in this sample, the `tbl.data` data frame would be the data I receive from each building. I'd have to manually create the `tbl.equipment` and `tbl.point` data frames, which I'd just house in *.csv files on my machine, or database (and be able to add/edit in Shiny). There's no standard for point names and there's not a guarantee that each piece of equipment has each point. Using `select()` helpers such as `contains()` or `starts_with()` is out of the question.

So I just created an Equipment table, which has parameters on the equipment, (in this case a multiple). Also, there's a Point table, which tells which piece of equipment and which category each point belongs to.

For this simple example, there's two sample functions I included. One calculates a value based on the the data, the other tests for a fault. My biggest problem in the past has been when a piece of equipment doesn't have a point, it stops the execution, so I have to manually go in and take it out or something else. I guess the workaround is to use `exists()` or something similar and test before running that piece of code.

Again, for this simple example, I just printed a plot, but the output could be a Markdown Document (which I think I've done before, but not like this) or Shiny (which I've created some simpler Apps).

**Conclusion**

The big question is "Is this the "right" way of doing it?" I'm sure this is pretty common and there has to be a really efficient method I'm not using. What's going to set me up for success when I start writing code to print out reports or taking this into a Shiny App?